# Prob. 3, Sec. 3.2 in Kreyszig's Functional Analysis: How to give a direct proof of completeness of this subspace?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Here is Prob. 2, Sec. 3.2, in the book *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwine Kreyszig:

> Let $X$ be the inner product space consisting of the zero polynomial and all real polynomials in $t$, of degree not exceeding $2$, considered for real $t \in [a, b]$, with inner product defined by 
>   $$ \langle x, y \rangle \colon= \int_a^b x(t) y(t) \mathrm{d} t \qquad \forall x, y \in X.$$
>   Show that $X$ is complete.

My Attempt:

> If $x\in X$, then $x$ is a real-valued function with domain $[a, b]$ defined by a formula of the form 
>   $$ x(t) = \alpha + \beta t + \gamma t^2 \qquad \forall t \in [a, b],$$
>   for some real numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$.
>
> Let $\left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in the inner product space $X$. Then, for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that 
>   $$ d \left( x_m, x_n \right) < \varepsilon \qquad \mbox{ for all } m, n > N. $$
>   Here $d$ is the metric induced by the inner product on $X$; that is, 
>   $$ d(x, y) = \sqrt{ \int_a^b \left(  x(t) - y(t) \right)^2 \mathrm{d} t } \qquad \forall x, y \in X.$$
>
> For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, as $x_n \in X$, so $x_n \colon [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function defined by a formula of the form
>   $$ x_n(t) \colon= \alpha_n + \beta_n t + \gamma_n t^n \qquad \forall t \in [a, b], $$
>   for some real numbers $\alpha_n$, $\beta_n$, and $\gamma_n$.
>
> In this way we obtain sequences  $\left( \alpha_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $\left( \beta_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and $\left( \gamma_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers. We show that each of these sequences is Cauchy.
>
> For any $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, we see that 
>   \begin{align*}
> & d \left( x_m, x_n \right) \\
> &= \sqrt{ \int_a^b \left[ x_m(t) - x_n(t) \right]^2 \mathrm{d} t } \\
> &= \sqrt{ \int_a^b \left[  \left( \alpha_m - \alpha_n \right) + \left( \beta_m - \beta_n \right) t + \left( \gamma_m - \gamma_n \right) t^2 \right]^2  \mathrm{d} t } \\ 
> &= \sqrt{ \int_a^b \left[ \left( \alpha_m - \alpha_n \right)^2 + 2 \left( \alpha_m - \alpha_n \right) \left( \beta_m - \beta_n \right) t +  \left( 2 \left( \alpha_m - \alpha_n \right) \left( \gamma_m - \gamma_n \right) + \left( \beta_m - \beta_n \right)^2 \right) t^2 + 2 \left( \beta_m - \beta_n \right) \left( \gamma_m - \gamma_n \right) t^3 + \left( \gamma_m - \gamma_n \right)^2 t^4 \right] \mathrm{d} t } \\
> &= \sqrt{ \left( \alpha_m - \alpha_n \right)^2 (b-a) + \left( \alpha_m - \alpha_n \right) \left( \beta_m - \beta_n \right) \left( b^2 - a^2 \right) + \frac{1}{3}  \left( 2 \left( \alpha_m - \alpha_n \right) \left( \gamma_m - \gamma_n \right) + \left( \beta_m - \beta_n \right)^2 \right) \left( b^3 - a^3 \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( \beta_m - \beta_n \right) \left( \gamma_m - \gamma_n \right) \left( b^4 - a^4 \right)  + \frac{1}{5} \left( \gamma_m - \gamma_n \right)^2 \left( b^5 - a^5 \right)  }.
> \end{align*}

Is this calculation correct? If so, then what next? How to proceed from this point?

I know that any finite-dimensional normed space is a Banach space, but I would like to give a *direct* proof of the completeness of this particular space.

P.S.: When I try to compile this code using WinEdit + MikeTex as an AMS Math document into a PDF file, there is a bad box due to the rather lengthy expression resulting from expanding the square in the integrand. How to get rid of this bad box?

Comment: Avoid the square roots! In your last display start with $d(x_m,x_n)^2=\cdots$ and then ditch all the $\sqrt{\ }$ signs.

Comment: Instead of all the details you can show generally that  any finite-dimensional real inner product space is complete . In fact any finite-dimensional normed linear space is complete. This is not deep but does take some time.

Comment: Any finite-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. Indeed, Gram-Schmidt process allows to find an orthonormal basis, so we can construct an isometry between that space and a Euclidean inner product space $\mathbb{R}^d$. Do you actually want to establish the completeness of $X$ directly from your explicit computation of $d(x, y)$?

Comment: @SangchulLee exactly. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of encoding your computation using matrix language: Define $A$ by

$$ A = [\langle t^i, t^j\rangle]_{0\leq i,j\leq 2} = \begin{pmatrix}
b-a & \frac{b^2-a^2}{2} & \frac{b^3-a^3}{3} \\
\frac{b^2-a^2}{2} & \frac{b^3-a^3}{3} & \frac{b^4-a^4}{4} \\
\frac{b^3-a^3}{3} & \frac{b^4-a^4}{4} & \frac{b^5-a^5}{5}
\end{pmatrix}. $$

If $T : X \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is given by $T(x_0 + x_1 t + x_2 t^2) = (x_0, x_1, x_2)$, then

$$ d(x, y) = \bigl[ (Ty - Tx)^{\mathsf{T}} A (Ty-Tx) \bigr]^{1/2}. $$

The fact that $d(x, y)$ defines a metric translates to the fact that $A$ is a positive-definite symmetric matrix, and so, there exist constants $0 < c \leq C$ such that

$$ c \|v\|^2 \leq v^{\mathsf{T}}Av \leq C\|v\|^2 $$

for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$. From this, $x_n \to x$ in $X$ if and only if $Tx_n \to Tx$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Therefore the completeness of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is inherited to $X$.